# Python: Logging exceptions with custom *kwargs

Tags: logging, exception, python-2.7

as you might know the python logging module supports the [definition of *kwargs](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.debug) to customize log entries. This appears to be not supported for [logging exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.exception).

My Question: Is there an easy way to use custom kwargs with logging.exception?

A minimal example follows:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

def create_logger(): 
    """ initialize logging using sys log

    """
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    form = '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] %(xyz)s %(message)s'
    local_log_handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log')
    formatter = logging.Formatter(form)
    local_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(local_log_handler)
    return logger

log = create_logger()
try:
    raise AttributeError("whatever")
except:
    log.warn('Alarm! Fire!', extra={'xyz':'POLICE'})
    log.exception('')
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logexample.py", line 27, in <module>
    log.exception('')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1172, in exception
    self.error(msg, exc_info=1, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1166, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1258, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1268, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1308, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 748, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 791, in emit
    msg = self.format(record) + '\000'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 723, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 467, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'xyz'
```

Syslog:

```
Jul 30 14:56:27 localhost 2012-07-30 14:56:27,131 [WARNING ] POLICE Alarm! Fire!
```

PS: A little background, I am writing a process with threading and I want to log information in the following manner:

[app-thread1]
[app-thread2]
...

Comment: If you look at the source code for `exception()`, you'll see that it calls `error()` with `msg`, `*args` and `exc_info=1`. In fact you can see that in the traceback above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use e.g.

```
logger.error('Message with %s', 'args', exc_info=1, extra={...})
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I replaced my log.exception with the following line: log.error("a %s", ['sth'], exc_info=1, extra={'xyz':'POLICE'}), but it would not appear in the logs.

Comment: two small mistakes on my part:
1. 'sth' instead of ['sth']
2. wrong log level

Comment: Nice work-around @vinay-sajip. Why was it decided that logger.exception should not accept extra data? It doesn't look like an accidental omission.

Comment: @Alex: It *was* an accidental omission. Now rectified - see http://bugs.python.org/issue15541

Comment: This still seems to be printing the raw traceback without JSON formatting :( the message in `info.error('my message', exc_info=1)` is formatted correctly, but the traceback is still just a text blurb with no additional formatting...

Comment: @rofls Why would there be JSON formatting? JSON hasn't been mentioned in this question or comments until you brought it up.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to apply JSON formatting to the traceback... I thought this was applying the OP's formatting rules to the _whole_ message, including traceback.