# How to use different loggers without passing logger variable? (Python logging)

Tags: python, logging

I have multiple modules that use the same `utils.py` package. How do I make the logger in `utils.py` differ without having to pass the logger variable from the callers(i.e. ClassA or ClassB)?

Very simple sample codes are as following. In reality, I have a lot of functions and classes in `utils.py`, and that's why I don't want to pass the `logger` variable into `utils.py`.

```
~/test-two-loggers$ tree .

├── main.py
├── configs.py
├── ClassA.py
├── ClassB.py
└── utils.py

0 directories, 5 files
```

main.py

```
import ClassA
import ClassB

ClassA.func()
ClassB.func()
```

ClassA.py

```
import utils
import configs
import logging

def func():
    logger = logging.getLogger("classA")
    logger.info("in ClassA")
    utils.common_func(logger)  # I want to change this line!!!!
```

ClassB.py

```
import utils
import configs
import logging

def func():
    logger = logging.getLogger("classB")
    logger.info("in ClassB")
    utils.common_func(logger)  # I want to change this line!!!!
```

utils.py

```
def common_func(logger):  # I want to change this line!!!!
    # do a lot of things ClassA and ClassB both need to do
    logger.info("in utils - step one finished")
    # do a lot of things ClassA and ClassB both need to do
    logger.info("in utils - step two finished")
    # do a lot of things ClassA and ClassB both need to do
    logger.info("in utils - step three finished")
```

configs.py

```
import logging.config

logging_config = {
        "version": 1, 
        "formatters": {
            "formatter_a": {
                "format": u"[A][%(levelname)s] %(module)s.%(lineno)d: %(message)s"
            },
            "formatter_b": {
                "format": u"[B][%(levelname)s] %(module)s.%(lineno)d: %(message)s"
            },
        },
        "handlers": {
            "console_a": {
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "formatter": "formatter_a",
                "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
            },
            "console_b": {
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "formatter": "formatter_b",
                "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
            },
        },
        "loggers": {
            "classA": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "handlers": ["console_a"],
                "propagate": "no"
            },
            "classB": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "handlers": ["console_b"],
                "propagate": "no"
            },
        },
}

logging.config.dictConfig(logging_config)
```

Result I want:

```
~/test-two-loggers$ python main.py 
[A][INFO] ClassA.7: in ClassA
[A][INFO] utils.3: in utils - step one finished
[A][INFO] utils.5: in utils - step two finished
[A][INFO] utils.7: in utils - step three finished
[B][INFO] ClassB.7: in ClassB
[B][INFO] utils.3: in utils - step one finished
[B][INFO] utils.5: in utils - step two finished
[B][INFO] utils.7: in utils - step three finished
```

But I want another solution other than this. I don't want to pass the `logger` variable into `utils`.

Comment: You have a bit of a code smell here. If you have a utility module, it seems like you should be logging from the utility namespace. If you have some reason to want to use the stack trace, you could always just create your [own formatter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5b5fb38cc70122354c95f0a88cecaffab7d0b523/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L514) to handle figuring out where the heck it was called from.

Comment: @WayneWerner `If you have a utility module, it seems like you should be logging from the utility namespace`. But the logs in utility will be less meaningful without the context (whether it's from ClassA or ClassB, if error happens in utility it was by which caller, and things previously been done in ClassA or ClassB before utility been called). But I guess this is also a philosophy we can try. Maybe we can make logs in utility independent, and add logs in ClassA/B to show the outcome summary in utility. This sure is an option.

Comment: That's definitely my preference - reworking your app to jump through weird logging hoops is rarely a good idea. You can also wrap the fn call in a try/except and use `logger.exception('problem with utility')` and it will kindly include the traceback even. So that's a handy way to approach exceptional cases.

Comment: Curious as to why you wouldn't want to pass the 'logger' variable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're looking for something like implicit parameters.

This is something Python doesn't have (*Explicit is better than implicit*).

But, as always, there is a more or less elegant way to emulate it:

```
class LoggerWrapper:
    def __init__(self, logger_name):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)

    def common_func(self):
        pass # do stuff here

logger = LoggerWrapper('classA')
logger.common_func()
```

Comment: Hi, this is the method I am thinking! Rather than`LoggerWrapper`, I think it's better to call it `UtilsWithLogger`. This is indeed an answer, but with two imperfect points. (1) It'll need `LoggerWrapper` init in both `ClassA` and `ClassB` (better than current solution, but not perfect) (2) I actually have multiple classes (namespace purpose) in`utils.py`. If I go with this method, I'll have to deal with nested classes, or, if I don't wanna deal with nested classes, I'll have to init all the classes in `utils` in both `ClassA` and `ClassB`. I'll wait if there's another method.

Comment: I don't understand your second issue... could you try explaining it differently?

Comment: Hi, about (2): In `utils.py`, there are multiple classes, e.g. `class CrawlerUtils - staticmethods crawl_json(), crawl_url()` / `class DbUtils - staticmethods insert_with_md5(), my_insert_many()` / `class OtherUtils...`. So if I go with this wrapper method, I'll either (a) add a parent class above these original classes, then I'll need to deal with `self.logger` in nested classes. or (b) Do `crawler_utils=CrawlerUtilsWithLogger('classA'), db_utils=DbUtilsWithLoggers('classA'), another_utils=...etc` these initialization steps inside ClassA and ClassB.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to use you the logger inside `util.common_func`, there's no need to pass it around. You can just use `logging.getLogger` to retrieve your logger inside `utils.common_func`. As long as you pass the same string (say `classA`), `logging.getLogger` will return the same logging object.

```
logger1 = logging.getLogger('classA')
def func():
   logger2 = logging.getLogger('classA')
   print logger1 is logger2 #True
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects):

> Note that Loggers
>   are never instantiated directly, but always through the module-level
>   function logging.getLogger(name). Multiple calls to getLogger() with
>   the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger
>   object.

Comment: Hi, but there are both `classA` and `classB` being `utils.common_func`'s caller...... And thus the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, assuming you're not threading your application, is to just monkeypatch the module attribute:

**util.py**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def do_something():
    logger.info('Doing something')
```

**whatever.py**

```
import logging
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def patch_logger(module, logger):
    '''
    Patch the given ``module``'s logger with
    the provided ``logger``. Return the module's
    original logger when we're done.
    '''

    prev_logger = module.logger
    try:
        module.logger = logger
        yield
    finally:
        module.logger = prev_logger


class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('A')

    def func(self):
        self.logger.info('Starting A')
        with patch_logger(util, self.logger):
            util.do_something()


class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('B')

    def func(self):
        self.logger.info('Starting B')
        with patch_logger(util, self.logger):
            util.do_something()
```

Monkeypatching is frowned upon, for good reason.

Answer (score -1):

You can change your formatter and use the `extra` keyword argument to pass extra dictionary arguments to your logging message. That allows you to pass whatever "module" you want to pretend you are calling the logger from.

So change your formatter from:

```
"[A][%(levelname)s] %(module)s.%(lineno)d: %(message)s"
```

to:

```
"[A][%(levelname)s] %(mymodule)s.%(lineno)d: %(message)s"
```

And call your function as:

```
logger.info("in utils", extra={'mymodule':'somemodule'})
```

In case you want to use the **real** module you are calling from, change `'somemodule'` to `__name__`.

I also though of maybe just overriding the value of `module` (so you have to change your formatter) but the `logging` doesn't allow that so it seems you have to change your formatter.

---

**EDIT:**

Just to make it extra clear, your `func()` in `ClassA.py` should be changed to:

```
def func():
    logger = logging.getLogger("classA")
    logger.info("in ClassA", extra={'mymodule':__name__)
    logger.info("in utils", extra={'mymodule':'utils')
    utils.common_func() #call the function without passing the logger
```

And in your `logging_config` dict, you should change the string `module` in `logging_config['formatters']['formatter_a']['format']` to `mymodule`.

The same should be applied to ClassB. And obviously you should remove the line of `common_func` which uses `logger`.

---

Further reference:

- [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.debug)
  (see the portion related to the `extra` kwarg.)
- [Python: Logging exceptions with custom *kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722035/python-logging-exceptions-with-custom-kwargs)

Comment: Hi, I don't fully understand your method. Could you paste all codes that should be modified? And are you sure this can generate the exact same output as the old one?

Comment: I think I was clear enough, but edited the post for further clarity. By the way, you don't really need two loggers/handlers/formatters in this case anyways, because the only difference is the letter A/B. You can change your formatter and add another key/value in `extra` to pass A/B. [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Hi, I understand your method now, but it doesn't fit my needs. What I wrote is just a simple sample. The `utils` and its functions should not be removed and be duplicated in different modules. In reality, there are many methods in `utils.py` and that's why the two classes share `utils`. Remove `utils.py` and make functions in `utils.py` back into `ClassA` and `ClassB` would result in many duplicate codes in one project.

Comment: I didn't say anything about your `utils` module. All I mentioned was `utils.common_func`.

Comment: `And you won't be needing you utils.common_func anymore` But I need that function.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question and add a comment in it. Please check out -> `# do a lot of things ClassA and ClassB both need to do`. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Edited the answer as well.

Comment: Haha :) But I need those logs inside the utils function. Please see my new edit to the question.